# Grouped Table View sends nil but Plain works perfectly

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm having issues when i group my tables it sends nil but when i keep everything as 1 array i have no issues and can't see what i'm doing wrong? here is my code for the grouped table view that sends nil, I hope this is an easy fix. Thanks

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var runeTitle = [["Freyr/Freya's Aett"], ["Heimdall's Aett"], ["Tyr's Aett"], ["Additional Runes"]]

    let runes = [[Rune(runeName: "Fehu", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Fehu.png"))!, runeDescription: "(F: Domestic cattle, wealth.) Possessions won or earned, earned income, luck. Abundance, financial strength in the present or near future. Sign of hope and plenty, success and happiness. Social success. Energy, foresight, fertility, creation/destruction (becoming).\n\n Fehu Reversed or Merkstave: Loss of personal property, esteem, or something that you put in effort to keep. It indicates some sort of failure. Greed, burnout, atrophy, discord. Cowardice, stupidity, dullness, poverty, slavery, bondage.")],

                 [Rune(runeName: "Hagalaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Hagalaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "(H: Hail.) Wrath of nature, destructive, uncontrolled forces, especially the weather, or within the unconscious. Tempering, testing, trial. Controlled crisis, leading to completion, inner harmony. Hagalaz Merkstave (Hagalaz cannot be reversed, but may lie in opposition): Natural disaster, catastrophe. Stagnation, loss of power. Pain, loss, suffering, hardship, sickness, crisis.")],

                  [Rune(runeName: "Blank Rune", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Blank.png"))!, runeDescription: "There is no historical support for a \"Blank Rune\" in runic divination. It was invented in the 1980's. It should not be used in a rune casting. If you bought a rune set with a blank piece, save it in case you lose another rune piece, but don't use it in rune casting.")]]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return runes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return runes[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Configure the cell...

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;

        let item = runes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = item.runeImage
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.runeName
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return String(describing: runeTitle[section][0])
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" {

            let rune = sender as! Rune
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            destinationVC.selectedRune = rune
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

}
```

SecondViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedRune: Rune!

    @IBOutlet weak var runeNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        runeNameLabel.text = selectedRune.runeName
        runeImage.image = selectedRune.runeImage
        runeDescriptionLabel.text = selectedRune.runeDescription
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you set your segue identifier in the storyboard to "segue"?

Comment: What sends `nil`? Sent from where? Your question is completely unclear.

Comment: Sorry @rmaddy yes i was vague on reading my question back :) my table populates perfectly in the groups i've setup from my arrays but when i click on a cell it should segue to SecondViewController and display all the information stored in the array but it returns nil.  I hope this is explained a little better. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to avoid using `sender` in `prepareForSegue` function. Instead, save the index of the item as a variable and read from it. Since sender can be cast to anything, it will be harder to maintain your project in future.

So you are looking for something like this:

```
var clickedIndex = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.clickedIndex = indexPath.row
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {

        let runeArray = runes[clickedIndex]// variable runeArray is the child array from runes
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        destinationVC.selectedRune = runeArray[0]// Now choose an actual Rune object from the array by index
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, by following your code i now get an error Cannot assign value of type '[Rune]' to type 'Rune!' any ideas what would fix this?

Comment: sorry I forgot to tag you here :)

Comment: @JohnDoe at what piece of code did you get this error?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I get it here destinationVC.selectedRune = rune

Comment: @JohnDoe Ok so your `runes` is an array of array and in each of the child array, there is only one `Rune` object. Are you intend to do this? Just making sure before I update my answer

Comment: I’ve shortened the arrays here so to make my code easier to read for this post. What I did was create a struct called Rune which gathers 3 pieces of information. runeName of type String, runeImage of type UIImage and runeDescription of type String.  I then created an array of 3 arrays called runes that was populated with the Runes struct in each of the 3 arrays. I created one last separate  array called runeTitle which was used to populate the titles for the Groups. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help it is now working perfectly with your code changes, I now have learned something new thanks to you !

Comment: @JohnDoe  No problem. Don't forget to vote up. Happy swift exploring! :)

Comment: Unfortunately it says I can’t upvote until I’ve 15 reputation but will do as that’s not too far off. I’ve just noticed when running the app the wrong information is being displayed when the cell is tapped? It’s displaying the info for a different Rune so I need to just check and see how I can fix that and then I’m finished :)

Comment: sorry i was hoping you could help me again i've tried to fix the code but can't seem to get anything to work successfully, Each of my 3 arrays has 8 runes in it so over the 3 arrays within the main array thats 24. when i click on a rune in the table it displays the data for a different rune and sometimes not even a rune in the same section selected. After several clicks on different runes and the back button it can crash.  If this can be resolved my little app is complete :)

Comment: @JohnDoe I am willing to help but this question has been answered and we should not keep asking and answering questions in comments. Please create a new problem with your code and where the error happens and the community will be happy to assist you :) happy coding